# std::thread only allows one argument

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to use std::thread in C++. My problem is that it only allows for 1 argument (the target function). This means I can't pass arguments to the thread. I don't know why. Here is my code.

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void run_thread(int num) {
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::thread t(run_thread, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error message.

```
test.cpp:9:17: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread'
    std::thread t(run_thread, 5);
                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:340:9: note: 
      candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__f', but 2
      arguments were provided
thread::thread(_Fp __f)
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:220:5: note: 
      candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
    thread(const thread&);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:227:5: note: 
      candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided
    thread() _NOEXCEPT : __t_(_LIBCPP_NULL_THREAD) {}
    ^
1 error generated.
```

I ran the line `g++ -o test test.cpp` to compile it.
I am on a Apple device.
Here is the output for `gcc -v`

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.21)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Can someone please tell me what is going on?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/r5e6Pe4h6)

Comment: Also voting to close, as the question is based on an incorrect assertion.   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread constructor takes additional parameters

Answer (score 5):

*it only allows for 1 argument (the target function)* - that seems wrong.. it can allow more, for more information take a look at the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) the arguments to the function are variable not not fixed

```
template< class Function, class... Args > 
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

try this one

make sure to compile with `-std=c++11` if not done already

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono> 
 
void f1(int n, int n2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Thread  executing "  << n2 << "\n";
        ++n;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}

void f2(int n, int n2, int n3)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Thread  executing "  << n2  << " " << n3 << "\n";
        ++n;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}
int main()
{
    int x = 5, extra = 7, extra2 = 9;
    std::thread t1(f1, x, extra);
    t1.join();
    std::thread t2(f2, x, extra, extra2);
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could use a lambda:

```
std::thread t( []() { run_thread(5); } );
```

After the complaint it didn't work, I wrote this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void someMethod(int value) {
    cout << "someMethod(" << value << ")" << endl;
}

int main(int, char **) {
    thread t([]() { someMethod(5); });
    t.join();
    cout << "Done." << endl;
}
```

I then did this:

```
g++ -std=c++17 Foo.cpp -o Foo && Foo

someMethod(5)
Done.
```

I don't know what doesn't work.

Comment: Didn't work `test.cpp:9:20: error: expected expression
    std::thread t( []() { run_thread(5); } );`

Comment: @DylanRiley: Explicitly pass a flag to opt-in to C++11 or higher; I'm guessing you're getting C++11 headers, compiled in pre-C++11 mode, and things are going terribly, terribly wrong.

Comment: downvoted to put emphasis on the other answer, which calls out that the question is incorrect and you can just pass the arguments to std::thread.  This is a case where the accepted answer is technically correct, but not the best answer.

Comment: @xaxxon reasonable. It was late, and I've been using the lambda pattern now, as my methods are always non-static class methods. std::bind also works, but I hate the syntax. I didn't even think to question whether the question itself was flawed.