# Error on passing arguments in thread in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to calculate the number of prime numbers between 1 and 3.000.000, using an option to split the program in an arbitrary number of threads. My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void prime (int z, int n){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = z; i <= n; i++){
        if (i > 1){
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++){
                if (i % j == 0)
                    break;
                else
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int n, x = 3000000, y = 0;
    cout<<"Enter the number of threads: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    x /= n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if (i >= 1 && i <= n)
        {
            cout<< "Thread "<< i <<": ["<< y + 1 <<", "<< x * i<<"]\n";
            int a = y + 1;
            int b = x * i;
            std::thread t(prime, a, b);
            t.join();
            y += x;

        }
    }
    cout<<"Number of primes: "<<count;
}
```

My error is here:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread'
            std::thread t(prime, a, b);
                        ^ ~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:220:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 3 were provided
    thread(const thread&);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:336:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__f', but 3 arguments were provided
thread::thread(_Fp __f)
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:245:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__t', but 3 arguments were provided
    thread(thread&& __t) _NOEXCEPT : __t_(__t.__t_) {
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:227:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 3 were provided
    thread() _NOEXCEPT : __t_(_LIBCPP_NULL_THREAD) {}
```

Comment: Compiles for me (with one small change `count` not declared) - live - https://godbolt.org/z/7qchTced7  Please tell us what tool-chain you are using ? And what C++ Standard you have set in the compilation options?

Comment: I am using vs code

Comment: VSCode is an IDE, not a compiler. You need to specify which compiler and compilation options you are using

Comment: Visual Studio Code is an IDE (without a built-in compiler) and can use many compilers.  What compiler are you using and what C++ Standard Option C++11, C++17 etc have you told the compiler to use.

Comment: Looks like the duplicate [std::thread only allows one argument \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66937653/stdthread-only-allows-one-argument).

Comment: Found the problem - you either have a very old compiler, or have set the language Standard to C++98 - live - https://godbolt.org/z/M8GfEW9Wv  Change the language standard to C++11 (or one of C++14, C++17 or C++20 if your compiler supports them).

Comment: I run this code in codeblocks now in my virtual machine the problem was  not solved

Comment: You expect to much from the community. You did not show the compiler command invocation. If you are using vscode, you configured the compiler but did not show this config.

Comment: What did you mean about config

Comment: tasks.json for vscode.